# How to use headerRight and headerLeft together in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I have been trying to use headerLeft and HeaderRight together but has been unable to do so. At one time, either headerRight is working or headerLeft is working. At one time, either the button is displayed at the headerRight position or at the headerLeft position. I want my both icons to be displayed simultaneously at the headerRight and headerLeft position .

This is my code in which I have created a stack using createStackNavigator(). In Account screen, I want hamburger icon to be displayed at the headerRight position in order to open the drawer whereas I want settings icon to be displayed at the headerLeft position in order to access the settings page.

```
export default function AccountStack({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Account" component= {AccountScreen} options={{headerRight: () => (<Ionicons.Button     name="reorder-three" color={"#FF0000"} size={32} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}/>)},{headerLeft: ()=> (<Ionicons.Button name="settings" color={"#FF0000"} size={32} /> )} }/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Help" component= {HelpScreen} options={{headerRight: () => (<Ionicons.Button     name="reorder-three" color={"#FF0000"} size={32}/> )  }}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component= {SettingScreen} options={{headerRight: () => (<Ionicons.Button     name="reorder-three" color={"#FF0000"} size={32}/> )  }}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Kindly help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are written in wrong way

Write it like this

```
 options={{
    headerRight: () => (
      <Ionicons.Button
        name="reorder-three"
        color={'#FF0000'}
        size={32}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
      />
    ),
    headerLeft: () => (
      <Ionicons.Button name="settings" color={'#FF0000'} size={32} />
    ),
  }}
```

Your return statement should now look like this

```
return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Account"
      component={AccountScreen}
      options={{
        headerRight: () => (
          <Ionicons.Button
            name="reorder-three"
            color={'#FF0000'}
            size={32}
            onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
          />
        ),
        headerLeft: () => (
          <Ionicons.Button name="settings" color={'#FF0000'} size={32} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Help"
      component={HelpScreen}
      options={{
        headerRight: () => (
          <Ionicons.Button name="reorder-three" color={'#FF0000'} size={32} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Settings"
      component={SettingScreen}
      options={{
        headerRight: () => (
          <Ionicons.Button name="reorder-three" color={'#FF0000'} size={32} />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```